# How to automatically discover Web Service by scanning LAN C#

Tags: java, c#, web-services, networking

I am consuming a web service (which was written in Java) in C#. The web service is available in LAN but at compile time I don't know the address of the server. I need to scan the network to find the IP address of the computer where the web service is hosted. I do know the port though.

At the moment, I have the following code, which is supposed to give me a list of all active IP address and then I am planning trying to find out if the write port is open, and as soon as I find a computer where the right port is open, I will know the IP address of the server, am I thinking along the correct lines?

```
List<IPAddress> ipList = new List<IPAddress>();
IPGlobalProperties network = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = network.GetActiveTcpConnections();

foreach (TcpConnectionInformation ipEnds in connections)
{
    ipList.Add(ipEnds.LocalEndPoint.Address);
    Console.WriteLine(ipEnds.LocalEndPoint.Address.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to scan every computer on the network to find the service? Can you modify the service at all?

Comment: @Steve What sort of changes would I have to make in the web service to make it easier?

Comment: If you have a range of IP addresses, you can use the netcat utility on linux (usually at /bin/nc) to check if a port on a specific IP is "UP". For e.g this simple bash script will identify the host for you: `$listOfIps="10.11.176.1 10.11.176.2 10.11.176.7"; for host in $listOfIps ; do if nc -z -w 5 $host 22; then echo "Service is up on port 22 on $host"; break; fi; done`

Comment: No, I have to do this programmatically in C#. And I know nothing about the LAN at compile time. @linuxfan

Comment: In that case you can attempt to connect to every (IP, port)  pair in your LAN with the connect() system call and check the return value for success. Netcat does the same but has some optimization in adding timeouts etc.

Comment: but how do I get the list of ALL IP addresses in the LAN?

Comment: No, using `IPGlobalProperties` will only provide actual active connections to the local computer. If I'm reading your question correctly, you don't know the IP to begin with, so NO connection. I'd start by listing the known hosts on your active `NIC` using `ARP` (e.g. type `arp -a` at a windows CMD prompt.) Collect the IP addresses listed, then one by one, try your connection string (I'm assuming HTTP) with each for the specific port.

Comment: yes, but how do I get the list in C#, I am not supposed to do it in a CMD prompt...    

the thing is, the software is going to be deployed at a customers site, and it is just supposed to work out of the box, I don't know what the IP address for the server is going to be.

Comment: @Marci-man If you can change the web service (or actually, if you have access to the computer running the web service), you could add an additional function to the service (or a new service). It would listen for broadcast messages (maybe a UDP packet) that meets certain criteria. Call it a "discovery" packet. The server sees this, and immediately responds with a message saying "I'm right here, and my IP address is ...". Two packets. And you don't have to know the IP at all. Note that UDP isn't guaranteed to be received, so you might have to try more than once.

Answer (score 0):

The web-services must have define the way you can discovered, for example you throw a broadcast with a specific soap message, in that way al services that matched with that soap message must response to you.
Also you can use DiscoveryClient class (C#) to discovered services, it allow you define scopes and other specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Is your C# application that consumes the data at a static location?

At build time, you could modify your Java application to reach out to the consuming service to provide an accurate location. This should reduce extra noise on your network. This should also reduce time that your application will hang attempting to connect to each IP address on the specified port.